# Register setup for bare metal

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader

I am trying to code bios level applications for fun. I tested my program on a vm and it worked but on bare metal it's very glitchy. I have heard that you need to setup segments and registers before coding at bare medal, but I can't find any resources on what setup I need to do. If it will help here is the code:

```
; I know this is not the proper way to print a string, but its just for testing

start:
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, 'H'
    int 0x10
    mov al, 'e'
    int 0x10
    mov al, 'l'
    int 0x10
    mov al, 'l'
    int 0x10
    mov al, 'o'
    int 0x10
    mov al, ' '
    int 0x10
    mov al, 'W'
    int 0x10
    mov al, 'o'
    int 0x10
    mov al, 'r'
    int 0x10
    mov al, 'l'
    int 0x10
    mov al, 'd'
    int 0x10
    mov al, '!'
    int 0x10
    jmp $
    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    db 0x55, 0xaa
```

And here is the output

```
Hello Wld!
```

I have tried printing other things and they are very inconsistent and glitchy.

Comment: If you want to program in real mode, I recommend writing DOS programs.  The environment is just a lot more predictable.

Comment: For BIOS interrupt `0x10` function `0x0E` you are supposed to load `BH` with the display page (alpha modes), and `BL` with the foreground colour (graphics modes). Which is the display page? Use interrupt `0x10h` func `0x0F` to find out. I also recommend you reload `AH` for each call, which has been skimped.

Comment: It still does not work, character 3-6 is always incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot sector with your program should look like this:

```
00000000: B4 0E B0 48 CD 10 B0 65  CD 10 B0 6C CD 10 B0 6C    H   e   l   l
00000010: CD 10 B0 6F CD 10 B0 20  CD 10 B0 57 CD 10 B0 6F    o       W   o
00000020: CD 10 B0 72 CD 10 B0 6C  CD 10 B0 64 CD 10 B0 21    r   l   d   !
00000030: CD 10 EB FE 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      
00000040: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
        25 x ---- " ----
000001E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
000001F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 AA
```

When this file is loaded by boot firmware at the address 0x07C00, BIOS will overwrite the memory at 0x07C1E by a 11 bytes long structure called  [Disk Base Table](https://euroassembler.eu/maclib/bioss.htm#DPT).
This will damage the part of your code responsible for displaying few letters of the expected message.

As [@fuz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417501/fuz) recommended, boot code is not a sane environment for beginners to start with.

Comment: Do you mean the BPB? Some loaders relocate the DPT to inside their own code but the BIOS doesn't generally put it there.

Comment: @ecm That's possible. I've got one old PC DELL with floppy drive left for experiments and AFAIR it used the memory at 0x7C1E as a union of BPB and DPT and variables for calculation of disk geometry. In any case, it's safer to skip those fields with `JMP $+60` being the very first instruction at 0x07C00.